# SMTP Options for our dedicated that does not include having to change the smtp in the mail client to send

Tags: smtp

Please keep in mind I am not a server admin so I will be as clear as I can be. The host of our dedicated has been of no help with this problem.  Here is my problem which my host of our dedicated server cant solve:

We have 2 clients that is not receiving the results of the submitted contact forms from their website hosted on our server. When checking SMTP on MXToolbox, it states that "Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname" and "Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner".

After 2 weeks of trying unsuccessfully to get our host to figure out the problem, I have started looking into other solutions.

One solution was to have Mailgun handle the outbond mail from those domains BUT its just a real pain trying to walk the clients through changing the SMTP in their mail clients so it sends to one server but receives from another.

Another solution I thought might work was to change the nameservers that currently point to ours back to Godaddy and let them handle the dns (and the smtp), and just adding an A record pointing to us, that way there would be no need to change any settings in mail clients. The problem with this as I see it is I dont know if it will work meaning in this case would godaddys smtp be used since its using their dns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered solving the "original" problem? I'm referring to fixing DNS reverse issue and SMTP banner.... It should be really easy (technically speaking)

Comment: Sure... but so far our host has not been able to do that. You state "It should be really easy (technically speaking)" to fix it, but yet no details on how.

Comment: Unfortunately your OP is not 100% clear. Please, can you confirm that: 1) you are hosting a website which include a sort of FORM-to-MAIL web-page; 2) when a remote visitor visit such page and fill the form and... click 'send message', an e-mail is automatically created and sent over the Internet to the e-mail address of your customer; 3) your customer is NOT receiving such e-mail; 4) your customer reported to you that based on checks he performed by himself (via MXtoolbox) your host has invalid DNS reverse and present a banner problem. Is this correct?